# FT232R TTL Logic Levels

Tags: digital-logic, ttl, level

I have an FT232R chip hooked up to my oscilloscope with the TX and RX pins joined. I'm sending characters directly to it via Putty. The logic levels I am seeing are 5V low and 0V high. I thought the output of this chip was TTL (i.e. 0V low and 5V high)? Am I missing something?

Comment: In UART communication, the idle, no data state is HIGH. The start bit is logic LOW, followed by multiple bits of data, and a HIGH stop bit. Is it consistent with what you are seeing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#Data_framing

Comment: 0V and 5V are TTL levels ... you are missing the fact that logic signals have `active` levels ... for example an active low means that 0V = logic `1`

Comment: @比尔盖子 - Absolutely correct. For some reason I assumed that no data state would be LOW. +1 for an interesting fact about the historical legacy relating to telegraphy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UART communication uses positive logic. In TTL, logic `1` is 5V, logic `0` is 0V. However, in UART, the idle, no data state is 1/HIGH, not 0/LOW. What you are seeing here is not inverted logic level, but simply an idle UART line.

The Wikipedia article on [Universal asynchronous receiver-transmitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#Data_framing) has a good explanation.

> Data framing: The idle, no data state is high-voltage, or powered. This is a historic legacy from telegraphy, in which the line is held high to show that the line and transmitter are not damaged. Each character is framed as a logic low start bit, data bits, possibly a parity bit and one or more stop bits. In most applications the least significant data bit is transmitted first.

For completeness, here's an example. I'm sending ASCII character "U" (`01010101`) via UART, 1 start bit, 8-bit data, no parity, 1 stop bit, 9600 baud.

On an oscilloscope, you will see the following waveform. Because the least significant data bit is transmitted first, binary digits of ASCII `U` is reversed.

[image: UART on Oscilloscope]